# How do I parse a JSON array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON encoded data like below and want to parse as a JSON object to get each record in a separate array. like `string[] name={"Prakash","Pruthvi","Pronnoy"} ...`

```
{"users":[{"name":"Prakash","phone":"1234","address":"Bangalore"},
{"name":"Pruthvi","phone":"3456","address":"Chennai"},
{"name":"Pronnoy","phone":"2345","address":"Mumbai"}]}
```

Comment: JSON.parse(...) will help. And if you need to transcribe the names like that I have found jQuery's map() method very useful in the past

Comment: output you want is invalid object syntax

Answer (score 1):

You can actually get this done in few Google clicks.

**Anyways here's what you want:**

```
       var str = JSON.stringify(YOURJSON);
       /* Converts to json notation */
       var data = JSON.parse(str);
       /* Converts to json array */           
       var i =0;
       /* loop through your data */
       while(data.users.length > 0) { 
         if(data.users[i] !== null && data.users[i] !== undefined )
            /* Last object always returns null */
            nameArr.push(data.users[i].name);
         i++; 
       }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse(jsonString)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: JSON.parse on its own won't deliver a string array of names in the format that the question describes...

Comment: I guess he need a `forEach` or `for` to push each element into 'string' array (with `JSON.stringify(element)` if he wants them as strings)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
var arr = {"users":[
{"name":"Prakash","phone":"1234","address":"Bangalore"},
{"name":"Pruthvi","phone":"3456","address":"Chennai"},
{"name":"Pronnoy","phone":"2345","address":"Mumbai"}
]};
var name1 = new Array(100);
var phone1 = new Array(100);
var add1 = new Array(100);
for (var i = 0; i < arr.users.length; i++) {
    var counter = arr.users[i];
    name1.push(counter.name);
    phone1.push(counter.phone);
    add1.push(counter.address);
}
</script>
```

Use name1,phone1,add1 for further use.